# JS Script using DOM running on pm2 server

Tags: javascript, html, dom, server, pm2

I have read that serverside, you cant use DOM. I've created a web application using DOM and I wonder what needs to be done to reproduce this code to make it work on a server, so the people on the internet can work with it. Here is a little peak of a code:

```
// Listen for export button click
document.getElementById('exportForm').addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
    setTimeout(exportData, 20);
    e.preventDefault();
});

// Export data function
function exportData(e) {
    console.log("Exporting...");

    // device details and time range details
    const devId = (document.getElementById('deviceInput')).value;
    var dateFrom = (document.getElementById('dateFromInput')).value;
    var dateTo = (document.getElementById('dateToInput')).value;
    var timeFrom = (document.getElementById('timeFromInput')).value;
    var timeTo = (document.getElementById('timeToInput')).value;
    const limit = (document.getElementById('limitInput')).value;
    const key = (document.getElementById('keysInput')).value;
```

When I try to run it on server using pm2 start app.js, it returns this error:

```
ReferenceError: document is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/cloud/sites/App/app.js:6:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/pm2/lib/ProcessContainerFork.js:33:23)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)
```

I've heard about JSDom, but I think there needs to be html included in a string and then I have no idea how to connect the css in there and so on. Is there a better way for me to make this work?

Comment: The document only exists in the browser. Why are you using browser code on the server?

Comment: This is my first project in javascript and I was thinking when I can run it in visual code localhost, I can run it on the server. Is there a workaround or I will need to recode this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Document object is a browser feature hence you cant use it inside server, Instead you have other features like the FS (File System)

Anyhow using JSDom may be possible, you have to rewrite using inline styles https://www.codecademy.com/article/html-inline-styles which is not a good practice and you should avoid it

Comment: Would you recommend some other way, how to create web application using javascript that can run on the server?

Comment: Well running JavaScript on server is called Nodejs, which im guessing you are currently running since you mention pm2.
I can suggest to use Express / https://expressjs.com/ 
It has built in template engine
Or you can go with any view library like React/Vue.js